# Error in connecting sockets in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am using this code snippet from an internet website, and according to it, this code works fine. But I'm unable to connect to server. Code and error are given below:

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    WSAData version;        //We need to check the version.
    WORD mkword = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int what = WSAStartup(mkword, &version);
    if (what != 0){
        std::cout << "This version is not supported! - \n" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Good - Everything fine!\n" << std::endl;
    }

    SOCKET u_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (u_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        std::cout << "Creating socket fail\n";

    else
        std::cout << "It was okay to create the socket\n";

    //Socket address information
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.3.34.131");
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    /*==========Addressing finished==========*/

    //Now we connect
    int conn = connect(u_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (conn == SOCKET_ERROR){
        std::cout << "Error - when connecting " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(u_sock);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    //Send some message to remote host
    char* mymsg = "success";
    char vect[512] = { 0 };

    int smsg = send(u_sock, mymsg, strlen(mymsg), 0);
    if (smsg == SOCKET_ERROR){
        std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    int get = recv(u_sock, vect, 512, 0);
    if (get == SOCKET_ERROR){
        std::cout << "Error in Receiving: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << vect << std::endl;
    closesocket(u_sock);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

[image]
How can I correct this error?

Comment: I'd start by looking both of those error codes up in the [winsock error code references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx). Note the latter is because you cleaned up winsock after the 10061 (connection refused), but then just kept right on marching down your code path as if it was still up and running.

Comment: Have you checked what's happening on the other side, the server you try to connect to?

Comment: Also, if you get an error it usually doesn't make sense to continue the program as if nothing happened, especially since you close the socket and call `WSACleanup`.

Comment: you have a server running at that ip address that is listening on port 80 ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Your network has no machine with IP address 10.3.34.131 that is listening on port 80. Or, if it does, that machine is rejecting your machine's connections to it.